# How to get Text from H1 Tag which has no arguments in Web Driver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
<html>
  <head>...</head>
  <body>
    <h1>Phonetic Translator</h1>
    <br>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" type="text/css">
    <title>electRa Phonetic Translator</title>
    <p>Today's password is:</p>
    <h1>
      MQQJXJLCQZ
      <hr width="80%">
    </h1>
    <p>The phonetic translation is:</p>
    <h3>
      ...
    </h3>
    ...
  </body>
<html>
```

Hi,

I want to get the text `MQQJXJLCQZ`. As there are two H1 tags after Body. I have used XPath to get the text value but unfortunately I am getting the error message `Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to WebElement`

The code I have written is :

```
    String PasswordxPath = "/html/body/h1[2]/text()";
    WebElement H1Element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(PasswordxPath));
    WebElement getPassword = H1Element.getText();
```

Please, can someone correct this code or suggest another way to get the text Value ?

Thanks,

**UPDATE1**

I have used string to get the text value, but now i am unable to put this value in the form using sendKeys. Error log as below:

> Element info: {Using=xpath, value=/html/body/h1[2]/text()} at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Nativ‌​‌​e Method) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknow‌​‌​n Source)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where `getText()` wasn't working. 
 Try using `getAttribute("innerHTML")`

Answer (score 0):

Replace `WebElement` by `String` in the last line :

```
String PasswordxPath = "/html/body/h1[2]/text()";
WebElement H1Element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(PasswordxPath));
String getPassword = H1Element.getText();
```

Comment: Hi I have used string to get the text value, but now i am unable to put this value in the form using sendKeys. Error log as below: Element info: {Using=xpath, value=/html/body/h1[2]/text()} at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Nativ‌​e Method) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknow‌​n Source)

Comment: Please, can you update your question with the new code. How do you call `sendKeys`?

Comment: String PasswordxPath = "/html/body/h1[2]/text()";
WebElement H1Element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(PasswordxPath));
String getPassword = H1Element.getText();
// Paste get Text to Text field
  WebElement pastePassword = driver.findElement(By.id("SecurityCode"));
  pastePassword.sendKeys(getPassword);

Answer (score 0):

As said, here is the problem

```
  WebElement getPassword = H1Element.getText();
```

getText() returns the String value but not WebElement. So you need to use String here, like

```
   String getPassword = H1Element.getText();
```

Comment: Hi I have used string to get the text value, but now i am unable to put this value in the form using sendKeys.

Error log as below:

 Element info: {Using=xpath, value=/html/body/h1[2]/text()}
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)